# Linking C++ Libraries with Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, homebrew

I have downloaded the external c++ libraries I need using Homebrew ,but I don't know how to link them with vscode on Mac (I am a beginner)..

when I include the Library it works normal, but when I use any functions from the library it shows me ERRORS : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:(all functions of the library I have included), and clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)..
How can I solve it ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Kindly do not tag unrelated languages.

Comment: ***vscode on Mac (I am a beginner).*** This is not the best setup. You need more experience in the compilation process to do this as VSCode does nothing for you by default in regards to setting up the task to link to external libraries. You need to first understand how to link from the shell with no IDE. Then you can modify your tasks.json to have it done inside the IDE.

Comment: Your car breaks down, so you go to a mechanic and ask them to fix it. The mechanic asks to inspect your car, but you left it at home and instead attempt to describe the problem by telling the mechanic that the car didn't start. Will you have a successful interaction with the mechanic?

Comment: ***error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*** Actually is helpful advice as it can help if you do what it says.

Comment: An alternate approach is to use CMake and the CMakeTools extension which will handle the linking for you but then you need to spend some time and learn at least some basic CMake. I expect a few days will be needed to get up to a minimal basic working understanding especially for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your language server does not know where the libraries are. I assume you are using clangd as a c++ language server plugin? In that case you should install bear (https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) which is able to produce a language server configuration file depending on your build system.

If e.g. you are using cmake, generate your Makefiles and then run `bear -- make`, this will generate a `compile_commands.json`, which your language server will then use to search for all necessary libraries.

EDIT: in the future please provide information about the editor configuration you are using, then we don't have to guess :)